# Word 2007 macro gone

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, vba

I have programmed a little macro for text search in Word 2007.

I tried to install it on other accounts in our company with very strange results. On two accounts it worked like it should.
On other two accounts after closing a modified document with the macro and the user form installed, everything was gone when document was opened again. How can this be?

Comment: How did you "install" the macro?  Is the macro in a "normal.dotm" file that you copied into each C:\Users\UserDir\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP directory or did you do it some other way?

Comment: First I exported the user form consisting of two files: ES.frm and ES.frx. This user form is triggered by this macro:                    Sub ES() ES.Show End Sub. I opened a new document on the user account switched to Visual Basic Editor imported the files and created the macro entry. The I assigned the call to a Quick Toolbar Icon. Everything worked. Then I saved the file as macro-enabled document and closed it. After opening it again the user form and the macro are not there any more. Only the icon on the Quick Toolbar which prints an error message "Macro not found ..."

Comment: Hi, Ok I think I know now how to install it but I don't know why it only works like this. Same like before but save it in an macro-enabled template and under "Normal" in Visual Basic Editor. Open a new document and execute it. Save it and close it and then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP has not answered their own question, I thought I'd help them so it:

"save it in an macro-enabled template and under "Normal" in Visual Basic Editor. Open a new document and execute it. Save it and close it and then it works"